# BLE compliance testing

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, pts

I was learning about the BLE compliance testing procedure by using the PTS tool. In the GAP profile test cases, there was one test case, GAP/BROB/BCST/BV-01-C [Broadcast Mode No Scan Response]. As per this test case, the discoverable flag has to be set to non-discoverable while the BLE device advertises non connectable broadcast packets. This implies that, the 3rd field in the BLE packet corresponding to capability should have value 04. Whereas, the ibeacon and eddystone packets send this capability set to 06. Does this imply that the ibeacon and eddystone beacon packets are not BLE compliant ?

Answer (score 0):

If you design a host subsystem you must pass that test to qualify as a host subsystem. But as an end product you don't need to use all features.